# Function with Generic List Paramaters

Tags: c#, generics

I am attempting to write a method that takes any kinds of list and compares there items. here is what I have so far, but it does not compile.

```
protected bool DoListsContainAnyIdenticalRefernces(List<T> firstList, List<T> secondList)
  {
     bool foundMatch = false;
     foreach (Object obj in firstList)
     {
        foreach (Object thing in secondList)
        {
           if (obj.Equals(thing))
           {
              foundMatch = true;
           }
        }
     }
     return foundMatch;
  }
```

it says there is an error with the two T's in the paramaters, and with "obj" and "thing" inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not inside a generic class you need to add the generic arguments `T` to your [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition

```
  protected bool DoListsContainAnyIdenticalRefernces<T>(
      List<T> firstList, 
      List<T> secondList)
  {
     bool foundMatch = false;
     foreach (T obj in firstList)
     {
        foreach (T thing in secondList)
        {
           if (obj.Equals(thing))
           {
              foundMatch = true;
           }
        }
     }
     return foundMatch;
  }
```

Note: You can use `T` inside your method instead of `Object`.

Comment: ... or make the class `ClassName<T>`

Comment: I now get this error on my Function call: "The type arguments for method 'MiTek.TrussEditor.Events.DoListsContainAnyIdenticalRefernces<T>(System.Collections.Generic.List<T>, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: and the call looks like: DoListsContainAnyIdenticalRefernces(selectedMembers, HighlightedList);

Comment: What's the type of `selectedMembers` and `HighlightedList`? You need to call the `DoListsContainAnyIdenticalRefernces<TypeOfItemOfBothList>(selectedMembers, HighlightedList);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Linq extension method `Intersect` to achieve the same result.

```
// to get a list of the matching results
var matchedResults = MyCollection.Intersect(MyOtherCollection);
```

Or

```
// to see if there are any matched results
var matchesExist = MyCollection.Intersect(MyOtherCollection).Any();
```

Comment: [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<TSource>` but OP's method return `bool` so it's more linke `var foundMatch = MyCollection.Intersect(MyOtherCollection).Any();`

Comment: @nemesv, thanks I completely skipped over that part when reading the question, DOH!